# Format numbers in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a number I'd like to format in a specific way when it is displayed in my view.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{### ##}")] 
 [Display(Name = "Postnr")] 
 public string CustomerZip;
```

in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerZip)
```

In the DB the values are stored as ##### so I get an error when trying this approach: "Input string was not in a correct format". I thought (or rather hoped) that the DataFormatString would reformat the string for me.

Any suggestions on how to do this the best way is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. The `DataFormatString` needs to use the {0:...} indexer style format string, like you'd use in `string.Format`. So you'd need to do something like `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:### ##}"]`. If the braces are supposed to be literal, then you'd use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{{{0:### ##}}}")]`. However...
2. There is no such format character `#` for strings. That is what you'd use for a numeric type. If you are storing the value as an integer, then you're in luck; just change the type of `CustomerZip` to int.
3. If you are NOT storing the value as an integer, but as a string (as you are wont to do with postal codes, usually), then you've got more of a problem. Like I said, you don't have any custom format options with strings. You'd need to represent CustomerZip as some custom type that is IFormattable, which you would define.

Answer (score 1):

Use following format:

`"{0:### ##}"`

See example on MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the Raw function like this:

@Html.Raw(item.Valor.ToString("##,###"))

It works for any type of data.